# keyframes only working with codepen.io does not work on brackets.io live preview or jsfiddle.net

Tags: html, css, css-animations, transition

Here is all my code... I have two divs that will be moved in opposite directions and exit the screen to redirect to another page. The problem is that the div with id="hat" completes the animation and the div with id="sock" does not move at all. I have tested it in browsers, my IDE live preview. Both did not work.

HTML:

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
}

.box {
  /*   TITLES OF CHOICES    */
  position: relative;
  background-color: gainsboro;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10%;
  transition: all 1s;
}

#hat {
  background-image: url(hat.jpg);
  background-position: center;
}

#sock {
  background-image: url(sock.jpeg);
  background-position: center;
}

div.box:hover {
  /*   CHANGE COLOR WHEN MOUSE HOVER  */
  opacity: 0.5;
}

*/
/* left exit */

@-webkit-keyframes pageExitLeft {
  from {
    left: 40px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    left: -440px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes pageExitLeft {
  from {
    left: 40px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    left: -440px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes pageExitLeft {
  from {
    left: 40px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    left: -440px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes pageExitLeft {
  from {
    left: 40px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    left: -440px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}


/* right exit */

@-webkit-keyframes pageExitRight {
  from {
    right: 40px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    right: -440px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes pageExitRight {
  from {
    right: 40px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    right: -440px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes pageExitRight {
  from {
    right: 40px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    right: -440px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes pageExitRight {
  from {
    right: 40px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    right: -440px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}


/*  ANIMATION SETTING   */

#hat {
  -webkit-animation: pageExitLeft 2s 1 forwards ease-out;
  -moz-animation: pageExitLeft 2s 1 forwards ease-out;
  -o-animation: pageExitLeft 2s 1 forwards ease-out;
  animation: pageExitLeft 2s 1 forwards ease-out;
}

#sock {
  -webkit-animation: pageExitRight 2s 1 forwards ease-out;
  -moz-animation: pageExitRight 2s 1 forwards ease-out;
  -o-animation: pageExitRight 2s 1 forwards ease-out;
  animation: pageExitRight 2s 1 forwards ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" id="hat">hat</div>
<div class="box" id="sock">sock</div>
```

The editor I use is Brackets. I have been trying to find a solution to the transition I am trying to do but couldn't find anything.I have tried to make the animations work and apparently the only place it works is in the website codepen.io I also tried to use it on jsfiddle.net still no difference.

Comment: Both `#hat` and `#sock` are animating with the Stack Snippet and [**this JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lvzzjcok/). Perhaps it has to do with the viewport size and the size of the elements? They're stacked in the Stack Snippet and the JSFiddle. If you reduce their size from `400px` to `40px` you can see both elements animating.

Comment: I have just tried it and it did not change anything. only the #hat element completed the animation. Checked the viewport as well still no change. I used display: inline-block to use the divs side by side could that be the issue?  or could it be because of the IDE I use? @hungerstar

Comment: In [**this JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lvzzjcok/1/) I reduced the element's size, side-by-side and both animate for me.

Comment: @hungerstar I tried it right now it worked in JSFiddle but I still do not know why it does not work with my IDE?

Comment: Are you saying that it doesn't work in your IDE even when you reduce the element's size?

Comment: @hungerstar exactly. I saw it work in jsfiddle when the size is reduced but in my IDE when I reduce the size it did not work.

Comment: That's not something we can really fix here on SO as the code you provided does work. We can't investigate your specific development environment and I personally don't trust _"live preview"_ features in IDEs as they're never 100% reliable. Test in real browsers.

Comment: I have tried that before too. I forgot to mention that in the explanation of the problem above. @hungerstar

Comment: If it's working in JSFiddle then it's working in your browser. Can't do much more for you. As stated above it's either an IDE issue or there isn't enough info to work with. Good luck with your issue.

Comment: @hungerstar Thank you for the help!